# ORA-31043: Element '' not globally defined in schema ''

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

I am getting an Error

> "ORA-31043: Element '' not globally defined in schema ''"

.
I have registered two schemas:

**SuministroInformacion.xsd**

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/bfqrtjtu5dh5tbmhmw5iqsk06

**SuministroLR.xsd**

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/bfqrxly04ys26vucnrfw24x12

but when i run the script, it fails:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE

    l_payload_xml     CLOB;
    l_payload_xml_2   CLOB;
    l_payload_xml_3   CLOB;
    l_xmltype         XMLTYPE;
    l_schema_name     varchar2(100) := 'SuministroLR.xsd';

BEGIN

  l_payload_xml := '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
  <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd SuministroLR.xsd">
         <sii:Cabecera>
            <sii:IDVersionSii>1.1</sii:IDVersionSii>
            <sii:Titular>
               <sii:NombreRazon>xxxx</sii:NombreRazon>
               <sii:NIF>123123</sii:NIF>
            </sii:Titular>
            <sii:TipoComunicacion>A0</sii:TipoComunicacion>
         </sii:Cabecera>
         <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
            <sii:PeriodoLiquidacion>
               <sii:Ejercicio>2024</sii:Ejercicio>
               <sii:Periodo>02</sii:Periodo>
            </sii:PeriodoLiquidacion>
            <siiLR:IDFactura>
               <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                  <sii:NIF>123123</sii:NIF>
               </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
               <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>123123</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
               <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>29-02-2024</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
            </siiLR:IDFactura>
            <siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
               <sii:TipoFactura>F1</sii:TipoFactura>
               <sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
               <sii:ImporteTotal>11652.50</sii:ImporteTotal>
               <sii:DescripcionOperacion>123123-LLC</sii:DescripcionOperacion>
               <sii:Contraparte>
                  <sii:NombreRazon>LLC</sii:NombreRazon>
                  <sii:IDOtro>
                     <sii:CodigoPais>US</sii:CodigoPais>
                     <sii:IDType>06</sii:IDType>
                     <sii:ID>123123123</sii:ID>
                  </sii:IDOtro>
               </sii:Contraparte>
               <sii:TipoDesglose>
                  <sii:DesgloseTipoOperacion>
                     <sii:PrestacionServicios>
                        <sii:NoSujeta>
                           <sii:ImporteTAIReglasLocalizacion>11652.50</sii:ImporteTAIReglasLocalizacion>
                        </sii:NoSujeta>
                     </sii:PrestacionServicios>
                  </sii:DesgloseTipoOperacion>
               </sii:TipoDesglose>
            </siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
         </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
         <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
            <sii:PeriodoLiquidacion>
               <sii:Ejercicio>2024</sii:Ejercicio>
               <sii:Periodo>02</sii:Periodo>
            </sii:PeriodoLiquidacion>
            <siiLR:IDFactura>
               <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                  <sii:NIF>123123</sii:NIF>
               </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
               <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>123123</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
               <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>29-02-2024</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
            </siiLR:IDFactura>
            <siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
               <sii:TipoFactura>F1</sii:TipoFactura>
               <sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
               <sii:ImporteTotal>11652.50</sii:ImporteTotal>
               <sii:DescripcionOperacion>123123-LLC</sii:DescripcionOperacion>
               <sii:Contraparte>
                  <sii:NombreRazon>LLC</sii:NombreRazon>
                  <sii:IDOtro>
                     <sii:CodigoPais>US</sii:CodigoPais>
                     <sii:IDType>06</sii:IDType>
                     <sii:ID>US31231231</sii:ID>
                  </sii:IDOtro>
               </sii:Contraparte>
               <sii:TipoDesglose>
                  <sii:DesgloseTipoOperacion>
                     <sii:PrestacionServicios>
                        <sii:NoSujeta>
                           <sii:ImporteTAIReglasLocalizacion>11652.50</sii:ImporteTAIReglasLocalizacion>
                        </sii:NoSujeta>
                     </sii:PrestacionServicios>
                  </sii:DesgloseTipoOperacion>
               </sii:TipoDesglose>
            </siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
         </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      </siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>';
   
    dbms_output.put_line(l_payload_xml);

    l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_payload_xml, l_schema_name);
    l_xmltype.schemavalidate;

END;
/
```

Error message is below:

> Error report - ORA-31043: Element '' not globally defined in schema ''
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272 ORA-06512: at line 97 31043. 00000 -  "Element '%s' not globally defined in schema '%s'"
> *Cause:    The specified element name has not been defined at the top level of the XML schema (i.e. globally).  Elements must be defined globally to be the root of an XMLType object.
> *Action:   Check the XML schema definition to make sure the specified element name has been defined at the top level.

Comment: You have defined `xmlns:xsi` in the root element of the XML but have not defined `xmlns:ssi` or `xmlns:ssiLR`

Comment: @MT0, even if i envelope it with SOAP it doesn't work:

xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" xmlns:siiLR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
..
   </soapenv:Body>

Comment: [First link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/bfqrtjtu5dh5tbmhmw5iqsk06) does not show the actual XSD of `SuministroInformacion.xsd`